# Is there a way of calculating the gradient descent of a Neural Nework output w.r.t the input with tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gradient-descent

I have trained a Recurrent Neural Network for time-series prediction and I'm now trying to find the optimal input for the network (i.e. the input that minimizes the output). At this purpose, I was thinking of applying a gradient descent method (for example, the classic SGD method) using the input-output function that is represented by the trained network itself. I managed to build a tf function that computes the gradient of the network output w.r.t. the input but I don't really know how to use it to implement the descent algorithm.
I attach the code I've written for my network's structure and gradient function. Any suggestion will be very much appreciated.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Concatenate, Dropout
from keras import regularizers 
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras import backend as K

#Define the first RNN
first_model = Sequential()
first_model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(lb, nbr_features), return_sequences=False))

#Define the second RNN
second_model = Sequential()
second_model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(ph2, nbr_features-1), return_sequences=False))

#Concatenate the two models' outputs and pass it to the overall output layer
MergedOutput = Concatenate()([first_model.output, second_model.output])
MergedOutput = Dense(ph1, activation='relu')(MergedOutput)

#Generate the overall model
final_model = Model([first_model.input, second_model.input], MergedOutput)

#Model summary
final_model.summary()

#Compile the model
opt=optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
final_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error')

#Train the model 
stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=4)
history = final_model.fit([x_train1, x_train2], y_train, batch_size=40, epochs=300, validation_data=([x_valid1, x_valid2], y_valid), callbacks=[stopping], verbose=2, shuffle=True)

#Define the gradient of the output w.r.t the input
grads = K.gradients(final_model.output, final_model.input)

#Define a TensorFlow function that computes this gradient
gradient_func = K.function([final_model.input], grads)
```